# How to prevent the list item from breaking right after the bullet if list-style-position is set to inside?

Tags: css, html-lists, line-breaks, bulletedlist

Consider this simple snippet:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>AnArbitrary</li>
    <li>ListElement</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see, the list items overflow the box.

But just let's add `list-style-position: inside;` and then they suddenly stop:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>AnArbitrary</li>
    <li>ListElement</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This breaking right after the bullet looks most ugly to me. I would like to prevent this from happening; I would rather like overflow.

But I still want `list-style-position` to be set to `inside` because I want to have full control on the position of the bullet.

Is there any way to do both? Can I prevent this linebreak right after the bullet while keeping `list-style-position` set to `inside`?

Comment: `white-space:nowrap` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `white-space: nowrap;` on the list items:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

li {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>AnArbitrary</li>
    <li>ListElement</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```